# Toggle checkboxes in a checkboxgroup

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have checkbox group which are 8 checkbox elements available ( days of week).  When an user click the "ALL" checkbox, I want to toggle all checkboxes. I tried to use `change` event of `checkboxgroup` but `change` event fires only while page loading. Is there any method or event in order to make such a thing?

```
{
xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
id: 'cb-work-days',
fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON GÜNLERİ',
labelWidth: '280px',
inputWidth: 250,
width: 530,
columns: 4,
vertical: true,
margin: '0 0 15 0',
items: [
    {boxLabel: 'PZT', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '1'},
    {boxLabel: 'SAL', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '2'},
    {boxLabel: 'ÇAR', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '4'},
    {boxLabel: 'PER', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '8'},
    {boxLabel: 'CUM', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '16'},
    {boxLabel: 'CTS', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '32'},
    {boxLabel: 'PAZ', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '64'},
    {boxLabel: 'ALL', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '128'}
],
listeners: {
    change: function(cb, newValue) {
        var val = parseInt(newValue['PROMO_WEEK_DAY']);
        var cbs = Ext.getCmp('cb-work-days').getBoxes();

        if (val == 128) {
            Ext.Array.each(cbs, function(cb) {
                // cb.setValue(!cb.getValue());
                cb.setValue(true);
            })
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Working Example**

```
{
xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
id: 'cb-work-days',
fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON GÜNLERİ',
labelWidth: '280px',
inputWidth: 250,
width: 530,
columns: 4,
vertical: true,
margin: '0 0 15 0',
items: [
    {boxLabel: 'PZT', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '1'},
    {boxLabel: 'SAL', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '2'},
    {boxLabel: 'ÇAR', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '4'},
    {boxLabel: 'PER', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '8'},
    {boxLabel: 'CUM', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '16'},
    {boxLabel: 'CTS', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '32'},
    {boxLabel: 'PAZ', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '64'},
    {
        boxLabel: 'ALL', 
        name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', 
        inputValue: '128',
        listeners: {
            change: function(cb, checked) {
                var boxes = cb.up().query('checkbox:not([inputValue=128])');
                if (checked) {
                    Ext.each(boxes, function(box) {
                       box.setValue(true);
                    }) 
                } else {
                    Ext.each(boxes, function(box) {
                       box.setValue(false);
                    })                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You forgot the function in the listeners of your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the change event *of the checkbox itself*:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    id: 'cb-work-days',
    fieldLabel: 'PROMOSYON GÜNLERİ',
    labelWidth: '280px',
    inputWidth: 250,
    width: 530,
    columns: 4,
    vertical: true,
    margin: '0 0 15 0',
    items: [
        {boxLabel: 'PZT', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '1'},
        {boxLabel: 'SAL', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '2'},
        {boxLabel: 'ÇAR', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '4'},
        {boxLabel: 'PER', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '8'},
        {boxLabel: 'CUM', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '16'},
        {boxLabel: 'CTS', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '32'},
        {boxLabel: 'PAZ', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '64'},
        {boxLabel: 'ALL', name:'PROMO_WEEK_DAY', inputValue: '128',
            listeners: {
                change: function(cb, checked) {
                    if (checked) {
                        var boxes = cb.up().query('checkbox:not([inputValue=128])');
                        Ext.each(boxes, function(box) {
                            box.setValue(true);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }}
    ]
}
```

And... You meant 127 for your "all" value, not 128... Didn't you?

Comment: it's 128, because I will convert binary after selection.

Comment: dear rixo, same behaviour, it's checking all but nothing happen when uncheck!

Comment: Nice :) But you're right, you'll have to do something similar to uncheck... And in fact for the rest of the behaviour that is a bit complex. The all checkbox should become checked when the 7 others are all checked, it should uncheck when any of them become unchecked, and possibly, all other checkboxes should be unchecked when the 'All' is unchecked... You can test all the cases in a single listener attached with a query in `initComponent` or, even better, a controller.